# Thread start in main method

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

I am attempting to start a thread inside of the main method, but it will not call the run method when i start the thread. I think it may have something to do with starting a thread in a thread:

```
package com.audiack.theForest;

public class theForestThread implements Runnable {
    private static int theBeginningTimes = 0;
    private static TheBeginning theBeginning = new TheBeginning();
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        thread.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        theBeginning.start(theBeginningTimes);
        theBeginningTimes++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are starting a `Thread` that doesn't have a `Runnable`, ie. uses the `Thread`'s `run()` implementation, which is empty.

You need to pass an instance of your class to the new `Thread` object's constructor.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new theForestThread());
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
new Thread(new(theForestThread())).start();
```

See more in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html